# Prefetch related objects of related objects

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a schema that goes like this:

```
Person <--> OwnershipDetails <--> Pet
```

where `<-->` denotes a one-to-one relationship. My aim is to model a one-to-one relationship between the `Person` and `Pet` entities, whereby the relationship also has its own attributes. The `Pet` object would then be accessed through something like:

`person.ownership.pet`

Is this the best schema possible in Core Data for this purpose? (emphasis on the relationship having its own attributes) If yes, is it possible to somehow pre-fetch the `pet` while querying for `person` objects? Something like `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching`, but more than one level deep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship needs to have its own attributes, that's a good way of implementing it. Since the relationships are one-to-one on both sides though, consider whether those attributes should move to one side or the other instead of being in the middle. If they really belong on the relationship, that's fine, but fewer entities are better if possible.

When fetching, `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` can have more than one level. That's why it's a key path instead of just a key.